# WordPress and MySQL - The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Tags: mysql, wordpress, authentication, php-7

I have just hit a brickwall here. Trying to install WordPress like everyone out there I downloaded the recent version of `MySql 8.XX` and recent version of wordpress with recent version of `PHP 7.xxx`.

Now i cant seem to set it up. I am getting

```
The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
```

error. When I checked some of the questions and answers on this forum some have suggested I add the

```
old_passwords=1
```

to the mysql `defaults.ini` file. I i do this my service wont start. I eve tried changing the user password to a secure password,and after many hours of trying, i have also discovered even is i put a wrong password i am still getting the same error...

Can someone help guys...

Comment: I think you will have to downgrade the version of mysql. https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-4-new-default-authentication-plugin-caching_sha2_password/

Comment: Surely the last answer I want to hear but it looks like I have no other choice

Answer (score 6):

Beside downgrading mysql version lower than 5.7, you can create mysql user with this command

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'
```

It worked for me.

Comment: I was stuck with `Error Establishing a Database Connection`, creating a user like this answer fixed this issue. (may help someone)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I can still use the latest version of MySQL with word press. When creating the database user with MySQL Workbench GUI tool I have to choose the standard authentication for my password option.

I also specified the Mysql 5x compatible password authentication when configuring the server using the installer.